# How Can I Parent A Cloth To A Rig Or A Mesh?

Tags: rigging, armature, cloth-simulation

I'm creating these flowy pants for my model, which required me to create a vertex group and pin it so the pants don't fall off.

Now that I want to attach these pants to my model, I haven't been able to find a single way that worked. after doing research, I tried the data transfer modifier technique, I tried to parent the cloth to the object, the rig, as well as the armature and still, when I go to pose mode to move my model, the pants stay right where they are.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aU-keowVfqLXkL3YRxRLGPahYA42veO7/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the current cloth settings prevent it to work, but if close the *Cloth* simulation and regive it, put the *Subdivision Surface* at the bottom of the modifiers stack, also leave a gap between the pants, it should work:

[image]

Comment: i'll try that now, do you think i should parent the pants to the body or to the armature?

Comment: parent the pants to the armature

Comment: nevermind, i parented it to the body and it worked!! thank you so much you have no idea how much i appreciate this. i was about to lose hope hahaha